# Run twice occurred gpu error on Google Colaboratory

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I want to test the FIFIQueue, when I use "with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):", the first time I run, it's just ok, but when I run it twice, error occurred just print cannot assign gpu to fifo_queue_EnqueueMany(the error detail is in the image below), anyone warm-hearted to help me？

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEWio.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrs9v.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per drpng's note on [Tensorflow: using a FIFO queue for code running on GPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40542099/8755609) I wouldn't expect FIFOQueue to schedule on a GPU, and indeed wrapping your code in a .py file (to see TF's logging output) and logging device placement confirms that even the first (successful) invocation schedules on a CPU.

In one cell run:

```
%%writefile go.py

import tensorflow as tf

config = tf.ConfigProto()
#config.allow_soft_placement=True
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
config.log_device_placement=True

def go():
  Q = tf.FIFOQueue(3, tf.float16)
  enq_many = Q.enqueue_many([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],])
  with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
      sess.run(enq_many)
      print(Q.size().eval())

go()
go()
```

And in another cell execute the above as:

```
!python3 go.py
```

and observe placement.

Uncomment the `allow_soft_placement` assignment to make the crash go away.

(I do not know why the first execution succeeds even in the face of non-soft-placement when asking FIFOQueue to schedule on the GPU explicitly as in your code's "first time")

Comment: thank you for your advice, maybe I should run the FIFIQueue on a CPU rather than a GPU~